# Onclick show the div with the targeted values filled in the input field and Regex validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/preetisingh/f8q09aju/)

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" role="form" class="payment_form">
    <div class="contact_details">
        <p>SHARE YOUR CONTACT DETAILS</p>
        <div class="payment_details">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="input_name" id="fullName" pattern="^([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-Z]+$" title="Type only characters" name="fullName" placeholder="FULL NAME" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="input_name" id="email" title="Eg: some@mail.com" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="input_name" id="mobileNumber" maxlength="10" pattern="^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$" title="Valid mobile number" placeholder="MOBILE ADDRESS" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact_summary" style="display:none;">
            <h4>Name : <span id='fullName'></span></h4>
            <h4>Email : <span id='email'></span></h4>
            <h4>Mobile Number : <span id='mobileNumber'></span></h4>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default continue_btn">CONTINUE</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('.continue_btn').on("click", function(e) {
    $('.contact_summary').show();
    $('.payment_details').hide();
    $("#fullName").html(e.target.value);
    $("#email").html(e.target.value);
    $("#mobileNumber").html(e.target.value);
})
```

I want to call the regex validation onclick. It's working when I am not using the jquery, but when i add the jquery to hide the div and show the the values filled in the input field the regex validation is not working as well I am not able to fetch the details filled in the input field. Eg if i fill the name input, whatever name i have written there, onclick continue button it should hide the input field and show the text which i wrote in input field. Can anyone help and tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: check your fiddle and inspect console there is an error $ not defined. you need to add jquery into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see in your code the button you is of type submit. That means when you click the form data will be submitted to the server for processing and also the form method you have used is POST. And also the code you are using to set the values is not correct beacuse `event.target` returns an element i.e `The DOM element that initiated the event.` as mentioned in [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

So you will have to change your code to something like this

```
$('.continue_btn').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.contact_summary').show();
        $('.payment_details').hide();

        var fullName = $("#fullName").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var mobileNumber = $("#mobileNumber").val();

        $("#validatefullName").html(fullName);
        $("#validateemail").html(email);
        $("#validatemobileNumber").html(mobileNumber);
    });
```

Or you can have this

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
        $('.contact_summary').show();
        $('.payment_details').hide();

        var fullName = $("#fullName").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var mobileNumber = $("#mobileNumber").val();

        $("#validatefullName").html(fullName);
        $("#validateemail").html(email);
        $("#validatemobileNumber").html(mobileNumber);
    });
```

Also one more thing i noticed is that you have two elements in your form with the same id. For all three input fields have span with the same id. That is not at all recommended. No two elements should have the same id as this may cause lot of problems.
Here is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8q09aju/4/)

Answer (score 0):

First. You have non-unique id in your html. So, let replace `<span id='...'>` onto `<span class='...'>`
However in this case your .contact_summary will looks like

```
 <div class="contact_summary" style="display:none;">
        <h4>Name : <span class='fullName'></span></h4>
        <h4>Email : <span class='email'></span></h4>
        <h4>Mobile Number : <span class='mobileNumber'></span></h4>
 </div>
```

and your event handler will look like

```
$('.continue_btn').on("click", function(e){
    $('.payment_details').hide();
    $("span.fullName").html($("#fullName").val());
    $("span.email").html($("#fullName").val());
    $("span.mobileNumber").html($("#fullName").val());
    $('.contact_summary').show();
})
```

Comment: Hi, I want to fetch the values of input field and show the text which i have filled. This code is not working and validation is also not working :(

EG: Onclick the button it should hide the form and show the details like:

Name: abc
Email: some@mail.com
Mobile Number: 7766553344

Comment: You need to use `.val(..)` to get or set value of input fields and `.valid()` to check validation status.

Comment: can you update the fiddle?? The .val is not working i tried.

Answer (score 0):

1. you are setting the wrong value with `e.target.value`
2. The id must be unique(there are dup id in your demo)

set value like this

```
    var fullName = $("#fullName").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var mobileNumber = $("#mobileNumber").val();

    $(".contact_summary .fullName").html(fullName);
    $(".contact_summary .email").html(email);
    $(".contact_summary .mobileNumber").html(mobileNumber);
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8q09aju/2/)